# Default Page Displayed for One User (No Problem with Other Users/Domains) - Centos Web Panel - Centos 7 Server

Tags: centos

HTTP Test Page is being displayed as opposed to the domain's public home page. Latter is located in /home/USERNAME/public_html and there is only one index.php and nothing else.

There are also no index.html in the nginx or apache public html paths.

How to release the grip of the CWP HTTP Test Page  ???

I tried rebuild webservers/rebuild vhosts files/rebuild apache
I tried delete user, and create user/using fix permissions property
I tried rebuild cwp (format/reinstall centos 7)
I tried check vhosts file (its correct)
I tried using [cwp wiki methods](https://wiki.centos-webpanel.com/default-page-displayed-for-all-domains).

**Note: I've 4 different IP addresses and websites in my vps/system. I use apache+nginx rev. proxy+varnish cache+php fpm (php7.0) This problem exists only in one user and one domain name. No problem with other users and domains.**

`Linux xxxx.yyyyyy.zzzzz 3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 17 23:49:17 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. After trying so many things, I realized that it was never in my mind to set the powers of the nobody group. I set the powers of the nobody group and the problem is solved.